# Can't retrieve Id from the database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel

I can't retrieve the ID from my database when I try to access it :

[image]

This is my database:
[image]

This is my event controller class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Event3;
class EventsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $data = Event3::get(['title','start','end','color']);

       return Response()->json($data);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
       $event = new Event3();
        $event->id = $request->id;
       $event->title = $request->title;
       $event->start = $request->date_start .' '. $request->time_start;
        $event->end = $request->date_end;
       $event->color = $request->color;
        $event->save();

        return redirect('/');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

I have tried adding the following:

`$event->id= $request->id;` into the above class but that didn't help .

Event3

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Event3 extends Model
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * [$table description]
     * @var string
     */

    protected $table = 'event3s';

    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * @var string
     * [$table description]
     * @var string
     */
    protected $filltable =[
        'title','start','end','color'

    ];
}
```

Comment: check   protected $fillable=[ ];  add id there

Comment: The store method creates a new element, the id will be filled automatically

Comment: What do you want to achieve here ? create a new element or edit an existing one ?

Comment: @OuailB Create a new element at least , it says in phpmyadmin that the record has an id but when I got to see via `https://social.com/events` ,I get everything back except the id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to modify your index@EventsController

```
public function index()
{
    $data = Event3::get(['id', 'title','start','end','color']);

   return Response()->json($data);
}
```

or simply call

```
Event3::all();
```

Note that the store() method in your controller is for creating a new element, the id will be filled automatically.

Comment: Just saw before you answered ,yeah simple mistake that  I didn't realize

Answer (score 0):

Found the mistake ,really simple one :
In the controller class forgot to add `id` :

```
 public function index()
    {
        $data = Event::get(['id', 'title', 'start', 'end', 'color']);
        return Response()->json($data);
    }
```